# ng-if unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have following line in my jsp

```
<div data-ng-if="data.length>1">
 <div data-ng-include="'moreThanOne.html'"></div>
</div>
<div data-ng-if="data.length==1">
    <div data-ng-controller="initiatePaymentCtrl" data-ng-include="'one.html'"></div>
</div>
<div data-ng-if="show">
    <div data-ng-controller="initiatePaymentCtrl" data-ng-include="'one.html'"></div>
</div>
```

and Js file is as follows

```
    $scope.initiateEvent = function(issuerId) {
        $scope.show=false;
        myService.setIssuerId(issuerId);
        $scope.show=true;
    };
```

moreThanOone.html is as follows

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">Please review your plan selection and
                        click "Apply" to start your application.</div>
                </div>
<table class="table table-format table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th width="50%">Plan Name</th>
        <th colspan="2">Premium</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td><img src="" alt="" class="plan-logo"></td>
        <td><strong><a href="">{{x.planName}}</a></strong></td>
        <td><a href="" data-ng-click="initiateEvent(x.issuerId)">{{x.amount}}</a></td>
        <td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary"
                type="button" data-ng-click="initiateEvent(x.issuerId)">Make
                Event</button></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Because my morethanOne.html has a ng-repeat and onclick of button or a link it should go and fetch data and render one.html therefore I am making show as false then setting issuer id and making it true again

> So expected behaviour is that onclick of button it should hide the
>   ng-if div then after that it should make it visible again

Comment: What happens inside `myService.setIssuerId(issuerId);`?

Answer (score 0):

$scope changes are not immediate, it only happens inside the $digest cycle so angular does not see that you change the value of show until after your function returns, you can make angular see it by calling [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

have a look at the docs: [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) and [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ng-model in div like

```
<div ng-model="data" data-ng-if="data.length>1"> <div data-ng-include="'moreThanOne.html'"></div></div>
```

Actually what is happening here is that angular runs $digest cycle after some time. so you need to place ng-model for live binding.

Hope this helps